# Shell with undo and full cursor support

Tags: command-line, user-interface

I spend a lot of time on OSX in Terminal running Bash on SSH.

Most of the time it's fine, but when writing commands I miss several "standard" text editor features:

- undo typing (/redo)
- cut highlighted text
- drag/drop text with mouse
- find replace (occasionally useful for large commands)

Is there another shell or a plug in that allows editing the current command with the UI of a "standard" text editor (i.e. with some of the features I miss listed above)?

Comment: Try [zsh](https://zsh.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever sees this, I've settled on [Micro](https://micro-editor.github.io) as my `$EDITOR` and use `fc` when I want to edit a command.

It has a really intuitive interace with undo/redo, cut/paste, and find/replace.  Unfortunately I still cannot drag text and the UI is still not 100% as friendly as non-terminal text editors.

Answer (score 0):

For bash, put:

```
-o vi
```

into your `.bashrc` file.

Or better yet, to affect input for *all* GNU programs, put:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

into your `.inputrc` file.

(Or use `emacs` instead of `vi`.)

The command line will then be in input mode by default, and entering `<esc>` will put it into vi editing mode.